# Rails 4 - Devise - Put the current_user.email for the comment

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, devise

I would like with Rails4 to assign the current_user.email to a comment.
This comment is assign to a book.
[Page book][1] [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/2mEoG.png
I succeed to assign the current_user.email to a comment 
but when i try to change the current_user with an other account, all the email of the comments change also. And i don't want that!

How can i resolve the problem?

Here some files of my app:

CommentsController:

```
    class CommentsController < ApplicationController

        def create
            @book = Book.find(params[:book_id])
            @comment = @book.comments.new(comment_params)

            if @comment.save
                redirect_to @comment.book, notice: I18n.t('books.comment')
            else
                render text: 'Error!'
            end
        end


        private

        def comment_params
            params.require(:comment).permit(:message)
        end
    end


view:

    <% if comment.message != nil %>
    <li><strong><%= current_user.email %></strong></li>
    <p><%= comment.message %></p>
    <% end %>

form_for:

    <%= form_for [@book, @comment] do |f| %>

        <%= f.hidden_field :book_id %>
        <%= f.text_area :message, :placeholder => "Message" %>
        <br />
        <%= f.submit %>
    <% end %>
```

Table Comments:

```
class CreateComments < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :comments do |t|
      t.text :message
      t.string :username
      t.integer :book_id
      t.integer :reader_id
      t.integer :user_id

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

Table Readers:

```
class CreateReaders < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :readers do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.string :email

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

Table Books:

```
class CreateBooks < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :books do |t|
      t.string :title
      t.string :author
      t.string :synopsis


      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Just use association Comment <-> Reader when you show email in view

Comment: @Alexey Brovikov : Can you explain more with code please. Sorry i'm a beginner in rails

Comment: no problem - show me please yours tables - comments, books and readers

Comment: @AlexeyBrovikov: See my edit please

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you want have assigned current user to comment you can place a hidden field to save users id (make sure you have configured associations in models):

form_for:

```
<%= form_for [@book, @comment] do |f| %>

    ...
    <%= f.hidden_field :user_id, value: current_user.id %>
    ...

<% end %>
```

Update `comment_params` in controller:

```
private

def comment_params
  params.require(:comment).permit(:message, :user_id)
end
```

and then, in view:

```
<% if comment.message != nil %>
  <li>
    <strong>
      <%= comment.user.email %>
    </strong>
  </li>
  <p><%= comment.message %></p>
<% end %>
```

That's it. If you need use reader model instead of user - you can do it in the same way..